# iOS: How to Sort with NSSortDescriptor a value from relationship?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, sorting, nssortdescriptor

I have two objects with a relationship in my Data Model...

1. Person {Name, position, Title}
2. Position {position, PositionSort}

Each of the above have their own class files (subclasses of NSManagedObject).  I'm trying to sort by PositionSort above.  I can currently sort by Position by using the following code.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position" ascending:YES];
```

I am unsure though how I'm able to access and use the PositionSort.  Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE: Added full function...

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorState = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position.positionSort" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorState, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


    NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(companyID == %@)", company.companyID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:searchPredicate];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"position.positionDescription" cacheName:nil];

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

With the above code I'm getting the following error at `Runtime`.

```
2012-08-12 10:29:45.499 College[269:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0xd6bd310> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key positionDescription.'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to sort exactly, but the following `NSSortDescriptor` can be used to sort the `Person` objects using the `PositionSort` value.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorPosition = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"position.PositionSort" ascending:YES];
```

perhaps, you looked for this...

Comment: In your answer which Position are you referring to? I should have initially wrote them out better... I've edited my question above to make them all more distinct. Thanks!

Comment: of course, the name of the attribute, I've edited my answer as well, but if you presents more code we could clear the whole process.

Comment: The error I included in the question makes me think that my relationship isn't set up correctly but it looks good from what i can tell. Thanks for the help!